# How to create RST codeblock without preceding spaces?

Tags: markdown, restructuredtext

What I really love in Markdown is that I can do the following:

1. Write ```` ``` ````<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Paste any trash I have in my clipboard
3. Write ```` ``` ````
4. I now have a working code block

In RST I have to do the following:

1. Write `.. codeblock::`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Paste
3. Now I need to indent all the lines I previously pasted

Does RST has any *simpler* way to use codeblock without the need of preceding four spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing similar in reST to markdown's inline code block. There are only [these options](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#code-examples):

> There are multiple ways to show syntax-highlighted literal code blocks in Sphinx: using reST [doctest blocks](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#rst-doctest-blocks); using [reST literal blocks](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#rst-literal-blocks), optionally in combination with the [highlight](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-highlight) directive; using the [code-block](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block) directive; and using the [literalinclude](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) directive.

If your editor lacks the ability to automatically indent `code-block`, or does not allow you to select the block and indent four spaces, then the best option may be `literalinclude`.  It's especially useful if you refer to the same code repeatedly.

p.s. -- Try indenting four spaces after the second <kbd>return</kbd>. I tried in PyCharm, but it didn't indent, but maybe your editor will do it. There are [several open issues for PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY?q=%23RestructuredText%20indent%20state:-Resolved%20).